# How to draw one shape within the bounding box of another?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

How can I add a circle where its diameter is on top of the bottom border line of a shape bellow it?
Example:
[image]

The only way I can think of is using negative margins with FrameLayout or RelativeLayout.
But I think negative margins are an "anti-pattern"/bad approach.
How can i do this?

Comment: Take a look at CoordinatorLayout and its layout_anchor attribute.

Comment: @mvai:Ok, interesting I never heard of that before